# Reduce load times for server side implemented internationalization in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, internationalization

I have following service which fetches me required translation for my app.

```
let translations = {
click_to_edit_image : 'Click to Edit Image',
add_edit_options: 'Add/Edit Options',
add_option: 'Add Option',
add_question: 'Add Question',
};

export default class TranslationService {

static init(newTranslations) {
    if (newTranslations) {
        translations = newTranslations;
    }
}

static translate(key) {
    if(translations[key]){
        return translations[key];
    }
    return key;
}
}
```

Now the "key:value" pair based translation works fine for a small set of data.
But if we have lot of strings to translate, this takes a hit.
Is there a way i can optimize this in react?
One solution i thought of was to query my "Translation Service" on "componentDidMount" to reduce the initial load time depending on the components being rendered. 
This will help me in consuming the service only when required by a particular component.
Please can anyone suggest me on this. Is this a good approach and scalable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you consider using eg. react-i18next? Using the translate hoc you only load those translations needed in current view.

https://react.i18next.com/components/translate-hoc.html

There are a lot of samples on https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/ using eg. the xhr backend to load those translations from your server. The good part you can separate translations into multiple files (per view + a common file; or what you prefer).

Comment: If you prefer you could also use https://locize.com to manage your translations and even publish them on a CDN automatically -> awesome workflow: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9NOzJhgmyQE